# How to run JFuzzyLogic in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

I'm making a FuzzyLogic Air Conditioner for an assignment in college and I need to get it running in Java. I have added the JFuzzyLogic jar file to my eclipse project but everytime I run the code it just terminates straight away. Can somebody point me in the right direction of getting this to work. Thanks in advance.

```
import com.fuzzylite.*;
import com.fuzzylite.defuzzifier.*;
import com.fuzzylite.norm.s.*;
import com.fuzzylite.norm.t.*;
import com.fuzzylite.rule.*;
import com.fuzzylite.term.*;
import com.fuzzylite.variable.*;

public class Lab1{

public static void main(String[] args){

Engine engine = new Engine();
engine.setName("Air Conditioner");

InputVariable inputVariable1 = new InputVariable();
inputVariable1.setInputValue(15.000);
inputVariable1.setEnabled(true);
inputVariable1.setName("temperature");
inputVariable1.setRange(-10.000, 40.000);
inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("toocold", -10.000, -10.000, 0.000, 5.000));
inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("cold", 0.000, 5.000, 10.000, 15.000));
inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("warm", 10.000, 15.000, 20.000, 25.000));
inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("hot", 20.000, 25.000, 30.000, 35.000));
inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("toohot", 30.000, 35.000, 40.000, 40.000));
engine.addInputVariable(inputVariable1);

InputVariable inputVariable2 = new InputVariable();
inputVariable2.setInputValue(30.000);
inputVariable2.setEnabled(true);
inputVariable2.setName("target");
inputVariable2.setRange(15.000, 35.000);
inputVariable2.addTerm(new Trapezoid("cold", 15.000, 15.000, 20.000, 25.000));
inputVariable2.addTerm(new Triangle("warm", 20.000, 25.000, 30.000));
inputVariable2.addTerm(new Trapezoid("hot", 25.000, 30.000, 35.000, 35.000));
engine.addInputVariable(inputVariable2);

OutputVariable outputVariable = new OutputVariable();
outputVariable.setEnabled(true);
outputVariable.setName("command");
outputVariable.setRange(0.000, 1.000);
outputVariable.fuzzyOutput().setAccumulation(new Maximum());
outputVariable.setDefuzzifier(new Centroid(200));
outputVariable.setDefaultValue(Double.NaN);
outputVariable.setLockValidOutput(false);
outputVariable.setLockOutputRange(false);
outputVariable.addTerm(new Triangle("cool", 0.000, 0.250, 0.500));
outputVariable.addTerm(new Triangle("nochange", 0.250, 0.500, 0.750));
outputVariable.addTerm(new Triangle("heat", 0.500, 0.750, 1.000));
engine.addOutputVariable(outputVariable);

RuleBlock ruleBlock = new RuleBlock();
ruleBlock.setEnabled(true);
ruleBlock.setName("");
ruleBlock.setConjunction(new Minimum());
ruleBlock.setDisjunction(new Maximum());
ruleBlock.setActivation(new Minimum());
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is toocold) then command is heat", engine));
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is toohot) then command is cool", engine));
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is toocold or temperature is cold) and (target is warm) then command is heat", engine));
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is toohot or temperature is hot) and (target is warm) then command is cool", engine));
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is warm) and (target is warm) then command is nochange", engine));
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is cold) and (target is cold) then command is nochange", engine));
ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (temperature is hot) and (target is hot) then command is nochange", engine));
engine.addRuleBlock(ruleBlock);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your code suggests that you are using `JFuzzyLite`, not `JFuzzyLogic`. You can read the `JFuzzyLogic` documentation [here](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/manual.html#runfcl).

Comment: Can you please fix the Markdown on this, and clarify what you mean by "belong"?